# $q$-dilogartihm function power series

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematics, special-functions

I was reading the $q$-dilogarithm function (Faddev-Kashaev)
https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9310070

How can I derive $$\frac{1}{\Psi(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \theta^{n} x^{n} /(\theta)_{n}$$

by using the following function:

$$\Psi(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \theta^{n(n+1) / 2}(-1)^{n} x^{n} /(\theta)_{n} \quad ? $$

Comment: I assume you have multiplied the two expressions and checked the vanishing of the coefficients of *x*, $x^2$, etc... by hand. Have you sought a recursion?

Comment: cf. identities of the [Pochhammer symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) in umbral binomials.

Comment: [Here you are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-exponential#Properties).

Comment: @CosmasZachos I obtain it easily when using the inverse relation the last link you point but now need to derive the inverse relation. Thanks alot.

Comment: Right: most q-function books have the proof... H Exton's, the Wolfram sites, etc...